# Nifi HandleHttpResponse octet-stream to JSON content-type

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using nifi 1.11.4 and I am using `HandleHttpRequest`, `ReplaceText` and `HandleHttpResponse` to mock an API request and response. However, somewhere between v1.9.2 and 1.11.4 they have removed the `attribute-type` property from `HandleHttpResponse` so the response is in `media type=application/octet-stream`. What is the easiest way to change this into JSON as I would like my application to consume JSON from this API?
Nifi flow attached:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Chris Johnston. You should be able to make a JSON response from HandleHttpResponse to the requesting application by sending JSON in the content of the flowfile that goes into the success queue(Q1) before HandleHttpResponse.

I am not sure what your replaceText is doing (update post with configuration), but normally you would be creating attributes from existing JSON (evaluateJsonPath), or changing/adding attributes with updateAttribute, and then using attributesToJson (directed to flowfile-content), to format the content of flowfile going to Q1 as JSON.

Additionally, you can inspect the flowfiles in Q1 and you should be able to confirm its JSON by noticing the mime.type attribute before pressing play on HandleHttpResponse.

If the content of the flowfile is what you expect and the mime.type is not set, you can set it with updateAttribute or add it on HandleHttpResponse by click (+) and add (key) Content-Type with value ${mime.type} (from UpdateAttribute) or just the mime type string you want directly.